# Error Occurred: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

[image]

above error occurred in context file when project load.
but when i clean & build solution it run perfectly i want permanent solution.

Comment: Look at inner exceptions/stacktrace when you click on "view detail"

Comment: View Detail Message :- {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}